# Observe flow in a lifecylce save way

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, lifecycle, kotlin-flow

**Situation**

I do load quite some data and then create UI elements from it - I do this for testing only and that's where the problem occurred.

**Problem**

If I use `flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)` it happens that I observe some data when my fragment is not active anymore (after screen rotation, theme change and similar) => this leads to `context` being null exception. My current solution does not have that problem.

**Current solution**

Here's is what I do currently and this seems to work properly:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Update UI based on a flow
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            DataManager
                .flowExercises()
                .take(1)
                .collect {
                
                    // to be save, we check current lifecylce state here!
                    if (lifecycle.currentState >= Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                        val views = it.map {
                            TextView(context).apply {
                                text = it.exercise.name
                                gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
                            }
                        }

                        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                            views.forEach {
                                ll.addView(it)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**New solution - NOT WORKING**

I'd like to switch to `flowWithLifecycle` but I can't get this working reliable. Here's what I tried:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Update UI based on a flow
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            DataManager
                .flowExercises()
                .take(1)
                .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
                // Mapping may need some time...
                .map {
                    it.map {
                        TextView(context).apply {
                            text = it.exercise.name
                            gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
                        }
                    }
                }
                .collect {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        views.forEach {
                            ll.addView(it)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit - final solution**

```
DataManager
    .flowExercises() // this is an IO operation and will be slow
    .map {
        // this is slow as well - we create many views for TESTING only
        // we check the context each time because during this phase the fragment can be destroyed
        it.map { data ->
            // if the context is not available anymore, this fragment is not attached anymore
            // => no need to create further views, the result will be dropped anyway
            // => yes, this work may be done unnecessarily...
            context?.let {
                TextView(it).apply {
                    text = data.exercise.name
                    gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO) // above code will be running on IO thread
    .flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED)
    .onEach { views ->
        // we are in state started => it's save to touch the UI
        views.forEach {
            ll.addView(it)
        }
    }
    .flowOn(Dispatchers.Main) // above code will be running on main thread
    .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)
```

Comment: Because you should be using a RecyclerView for rendering views like this instead of manually adding as many views as there are items, then you wouldn't have this sort of issue

Comment: this is not the problem - if the flow is slow and I simply update a view's text the same issue will happen... and as I said, this is just a test code

Comment: I don’t see how the same issue could happen in a RecyclerView because it will at most be updating as many TextViews as will fit on screen at any one time. What is the context of `flowExercises()`? If it is a blocking function, I would recommend changing it to a suspend function that internally delegates to the appropriate dispatcher so you don’t have to worry about that downstream. In my opinion, when working with coroutines, blocking functions should exist only in low-level, private code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, because you didn't say what you meant by "not working" or "working reliable", but you're mixing two different lifecycle scopes. I think you should precede `lifecycleScope.launch` with `viewLifecycleOwner`.

Actually, your original code looks less reliable to me because if the item arrives while the Fragment is in the background, it will simply be dropped.

I'm also not sure if you could be getting unpredictable behavior by instantiating your TextViews off the main thread. But it's probably fine since they aren't being drawn yet.

However, since you're using `take(1)`, You could just be using `first()` instead of collecting the Flow, and it would be simpler. No more using `map` and `forEach` on a single item. You can use `launchWhenStarted` to suspend until its safe to create your TextView:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Update UI based on a flow
        viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            DataManager
                .flowExercises()
                .first()
                .forEach {
                    val textView = TextView(context).apply {
                            text = it.exercise.name
                            gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
                        }
                    ll.addView(textView)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Side note, you don't need to specify `Dispatchers.IO` since you aren't calling any blocking functions, and removing that will allow you to also remove `withContext`.

Comment: you are right with the `viewLifecycleOwner`. Still your solution does all the heavy work (the flow + view creation) inside the main thread which is not what I want. I think I found my issue - it's simply that if you do too much work after `flowWithLifecycle` you need to make sure that after this work has finished you are still in the correct state - I added my updated solution with comments to my question, let me know if you still have some feedback